# They lived on a planet and their home was named Fang

Tags: story-identification

I can only remember bits and pieces of this book:

- The beginning the book describes someone running really fast
- They lived on a planet and their home was named Fang
- There was a colony of big wolves who, when they went into battle got into big suits of armor
- They were invaded by another species and they started off winning but then the other people had a lot of people
- I think it was a book series.

Hopefully someone can help me remember the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like it could be Battle of the Fang by Chris Wraight.

This is a Warhammer 40K novel about the Space Wolves chapter of Space Marines. They live on a planet and their fortress is called the Fang. They are genetically enhanced humans and wolves figure heavily in their heraldry, and they also have some wolf-like traits.

When they go into battle they wear large suits of powered armour.

It's been a while since I read it and I don't remember someone running fast, but in the novel their planet is invaded by a rival chapter of enemy Space Marines. They are heavily outnumbered as the bulk of their army has been drawn away to another planet.

EDIT - If this isn't it, then it could also be another Space Wolves novel from the Warhammer series published by Black Library.

Comment: Believe that is it. Thank you very much